# Could not find method implementation Flutter Android app

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, android-gradle-plugin

I have a brand new **Flutter** application in which I am trying to add Notification from native Android service receiver.

When I write the code related to **NotificationCompat**, Android Studio suggest to add **com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0** dependency to **build.gradle** file. But once I add this dependency in the **build.gradle** file it starts showing gradle build failed errors.

Error:

> Could not find method implementation() for arguments
>   [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] on object of type
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Gradle file

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
   }
 }

   rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
  subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
  } 
 subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
 }

 task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
 }

  dependencies {
   implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
 }
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: Please show your gradle file

Comment: I have added the grade file

Comment: I think you added dependencies into the wrong file. You should have an app folder with a Gradle file and already a dependencies block there

Comment: Actually when I add the NotificationCompat in my java file, the Android studio shows error and ask to add the dependency in the build.gradle file. As and when I click add, it places the dependency here by itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with `firebase-messaging` the problem has gone once I have moved the dependency from `build.gradle` to `app/build.gradle`